# changing the value of "onclick" of a td from javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am trying to change the value of "onclick" of a td from a function in javascript.
I've tried everything i can think of and i've searched it on the internet but nothing worked, exept from this code below, but the problem with it is that it's executing what i want the value of onclick to be instead of changing it.

```
<div align="center" id="bodyC">
<table width="800" height="410">
<td class="bodyCC">
    <table id="MYtable" class="MYtable" border="0" width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="50">
    <td id="one" class="one" onclick=""></td>
    <td id="two" class="two" onclick=""></td>
    <td id="three" class="three" onclick=""></td>
    </table>
</td>
</table>
</div>


function download()
{
<!-- this function is called when the "Download" button on the website's menu is pressed, and is soppused to change the "body" table so when the sells are clicked an alert will pop.-->
document.getElementById('one').onclick=alert("A..!");
document.getElementById('two').onclick=alert("B..!");
document.getElementById('three').onclick=alert("C..!");
}
```

any help?

p.s. there are no errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write

```
document.getElementById('one').onclick=alert("A..!");
```

you set as `onclick` handler the the returned value of `alert("A..!")` : it's `undefined`. So this can't work.

What you need is a function definition :

```
document.getElementById('one').onclick = function() {alert("A..!");};
```

Alternatively, you could have :

```
function myfunc() {
    alert("A..!");
} 
document.getElementById('one').onclick = myfunc;
```

But it's fine to write anonymous function definitions, as it keeps the code in the place where it is used and thus is often cleaner.

You also need to have you javascript inside a script element :

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('one').onclick = function() {alert("A..!");};
    document.getElementById('two').onclick = function() {alert("B..!");};
    document.getElementById('three').onclick = function() {alert("C..!");};
</script>
```

Here is a complete, fixed, tested version of your page :

```
<div align="center" id="bodyC">
<table width="800" height="100"><tr>
<td class="bodyCC">
    <table id="MYtable" class="MYtable" border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="50"><tr>
    <td id="one" class="one" onclick="">ONE</td>
    <td id="two" class="two" onclick="">TWO</td>
        <td id="three" class="three" onclick="">THREE</td></tr>
    </table>
    </td></tr>
</table>
    <span onclick="download();">CLICK HERE</span>
</div>
<script>
// this function is called when the "Download" button on the website's menu
// is pressed, and is soppused to change the "body" table so when the sells
// are clicked an alert will pop.
function download() {
   document.getElementById('one').onclick=function(){alert("A..!");};
   document.getElementById('two').onclick=function(){alert("B..!");};
   document.getElementById('three').onclick=function(){alert("C..!");};
} 
</script>​​​​​​​​​​
```

(I fixed also the HTML comments, and the missing tr)

You can click test it **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/c3Bj6/)** : click on "CLICK HERE" to activate the ability to click on the three other sections (one, two, three).

Comment: I already tried it this way and i tried it again now, but it's not working. the "ctrl+shift+J" tool on chrome says that onclick is empty

Comment: Remove `onclick=""` from you HTML.

Comment: i have it inside <script type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: i said i have it inside <script type="text/javascript"></script>, i copied here just parts of the code

Comment: well, it's doing the same problem i said i have (but the problem with it is that it's executing what i want the value of onclick to be instead of changing it.). When you press the "CLICK HERE" button it just pops out the three alerts right away

Comment: It pops out three alerts because that's what you're telling it to do. You're asking for an entirely different thing now: you want a different alert message to appear every time you click "CLICK HERE". Am I right?

Comment: no, i need that every time (after the CLICK HERE button is pressed) you click on a cell (one, two, or three) an alert will pop. each cell has its own text in the alert

Comment: So you mean you want to click "CLICK HERE" and then click a cell for an alert and do the process over again for a different cell; that you must click "CLICK HERE" AGAIN in order to get the alert from clicking the other cell?

Comment: (dystroy) its great, thank you, but i've tried to copy it to my code and, how can i get this part <span onclick="download();">CLICK HERE</span> to work on a td cell?

Comment: @user1495726 you can set the onclick="download()" on a TD, not just on a span.

Comment: i know but it's not working for me when i put your code in mine T_T    probably cause i changed something wrong.. wow it's annoying

Comment: well, that's the whole code, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7mpTS/2/) (although the 'result' part in that website is too small),  i really can't find what's wrong.. i've just started to learn web developing three or four days ago but it's still annoying that i can't find the problem..    @dystroy

Comment: @noamg97 : I don't know why the three TD in your fiddle aren't clickable and aren't even modifiable normally by css (I couldn't add a "cursor:pointer"). There is something strange, maybe related to jsfiddle.net.

Comment: i have no idea what you just said ^_^ well i only started web developing a few days ago (it was pretty easy until now). so.. what should i do..?